# Audio Programming for Games - General Questions

Tags: sound-design, gameaudio, programming

I'm gearing up to start a degree in Computer Science. My goal is to take my audio/game industry knowledge, combine it with coding experience, and jump into Audio Programming for games a few years from now.

I was wondering if any recruiters, programmers, or audio guys out there have any experience with an Audio Programming role or the interview process for that position.

Example - Are there specific things on a resume/portfolio that recruiters looking for? Do you primarily search for people with C++ experience, or do you look for someone who is well-rounded in different languages? Do you have any interview testing processes that a candidate should be prepared for? Does the Audio Programmer typically have to work his way up in your company, or can it be an outside hire?

Thanks for your time reading/answering these questions. I have researched Audio Programmer job postings/requirements, but am a bit unfamiliar with the hiring process for this specific position. Before I start my classes, I just wanted to make sure I'm heading and the right direction and prepare myself as much as I can for this type of position. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all your help, guys. I guess I should've mentioned in the post that I've worked on some AAA titles as a Dialogue Editor/Audio Designer for about 4 years. So I already am experienced with DAWs and middleware.

Comment: However, I'm looking to make the jump into the programming side. I've been slowly teaching myself Python, Java, and some C++ for the past year or so in my spare time, but I'm still a beginner in it all. So I have decided to dive deeper into programming by taking Computer Science courses. I love working in game audio, and I think it would be great to combine the two skills.

This definitely gives me a good reference point on what things to focus on while I pursue my CS degree. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about sound design.

Answer (score 1):

The best skill for audio programmers would be - strong coding skills (i guess C++ syntax) and good knowledge of middleware such as Wwise and FMod.

Knowledge of audio editors (SoundForge, Audio Audition, Audacity etc.) and DAWs (ProTools, Logic, Cubase etc.) is most of the a time a well recieved plus

Modern audio technique can also be useful like - using compression to duck sounds or convolution reverb and reflection for spaces can be useful

Answer (score 0):

Well-roundedness in languages can mean that one's willing to change languages, if one needs to. In many cases one needs to, since it may be some library that forces one to use another language (e.g. through binding).

"Audio programming" can be both in-house or outsourced. In-house is probably more common since audio programming often needs to be able to deal with the source code in a very direct way.

On the skill level, audio programming is a job that most people with a formal degree in CS or EE or even mathematics should be able to tackle, so I would be looking at those and additionally a demonstrated interest in audio DSP (i.e. you would have a portfolio of e.g. VST plug-ins, game audio demos or similar).

I think that once you actually start to build a portfolio, then you'll find what kind of stuff is relevant and contemporary for audio programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my website and resume for reference. Might help you out in seeing what sort of skills are required! Shoot me an email if you have any questions.

Website: www.deepakchennakkadan.com